# Transfer iTunes from PC to Mac?

Tags: macos, itunes

I've just switched to Mac. Everything was running smoothly so far. Now I need to copy my iTunes library (+6,000 songs and videos) from my old windows computer to my new Mac. I've heard it can be done manually but it's such a pain.

Is there a better way to move iTunes?

Answer (score 1):

There's a very good article at Macworld ([here](http://www.macworld.com/article/146958/2010/03/move_itunes_windows_mac.html)) that I used when I transferred my library across. It does involve a bit of manual work, but it's not too painful.

Answer (score 0):

If the bulk of your library is stuff that you purchased from iTunes, and if you have an iPod that is formatted for windows, then you might be able to use the iPod to transfer the purchases from windows to the Mac.

http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1329

I've done this to go from Mac to PC and it worked pretty well. Then you can move the non-iTunes store stuff manually.